# Limit of Absolute Value Sinc Squared?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Recall $| \operatorname{sinc}(x)| = | f| / | g|$. 
Choose $f = \sin(\pi x)$ and $g = \pi x$. 
Case $| \operatorname{sinc}(x)| \to 0/0$, because $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(\pi x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x = 0$ so possible tricky L'Hopital case.

**Finding limit by considering even/odd**. 
I feel that this approach as in the first comment is not sufficient. 
I agree that both functions are odd so the total function is even. 
I cannot hold the indefinite form of the both cases and I cannot promise that both suppress to $L$, so I cannot claim that the expression suppresses to $L$.

**Finding limit by logarithm and Algebraic Transformation**. 
I think using the log allows us to use the basic algebraic transformation. 
The log form also reveals that the case is not so simple. 
Let $y(x) = \sin(\pi x) / (\pi x)$. 
Let $\ln y = \ln ( \sin \pi x ) - \ln(\pi x)$. 
Consider

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln \sin(\pi x) - \ln(\pi x) = ...
\end{equation}
which limit does not seem to exist (Wolfram Alpha), but
where $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln(\pi x) = - \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln \sin(\pi x) = ...$

### Sinc Squared

It may be useful to consider the absolute value of the Sinc squared instead, see [here](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Sinc-squared_function).
Recall
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{sinc}^{2}(\pi x) = 
\left\lbrace \begin{array}{rl} 1, & x = 0 \\ \frac{\sin^2 \pi x}{(\pi x)^2}, & x \ne 0 \\ \end{array}\right.
\end{equation} 
Consider $\lim_{x \to 0^+}   |\operatorname{sinc}^{2}(\pi x)| = ...$

How can you evaluate the limit of the absolute value Squared Sinc?

Comment: $\sin(\pi x)$ and $\pi x$ are both odd functions; $\sin(\pi x)/\pi x$ is therefore even, and $\lim x\to 0+$ must be the same as $\lim x\to 0-$.  Furthermore, if $\lim x\to 0$ exists and equals $L$, then both $\lim x\to 0+$ and $\lim x\to 0-$ must exist and equal $L$.